# Need to configure Group Level JVM / Node Level JVM / both?

Tags: jboss-eap-6

In Management Console, I have seen JVM Configuration for Server Group level as well as Server level.

Do we need to configure both JVM ( Group and Node ) ? I am asking it for curious in the JBoss EAP6.0 Memory configurtion.

> We are having one physical machine. In that, We are having one jboss
>   instance (6.0) with 5 different groups configured, as well as
>   Configured memory for those group level Servers. Each group having two
>   nodes in that same instance. **We didn't configured jvm for Node
>   level, Since we have done it for Group level.**

I am having the following question, based on my current scenario (Didn't configured Node Level JVM).

1 ) What is the Default Node level JVM Configuration, If i haven't specified any Configuration at Node Level?

2 ) Group Level Configuration will affect Node Level Configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Management Console, We could configure memory in multiple levels. Jboss EAP Management provides that feature to us. Those levels are following.

**1. Domain Level** ( To configure Domain Controller, Need to configure in **domain.conf**)

**2. Host Level** ( To Configure Host Controller, Need to configure in **host.xml**)

**3. Server Group Level** ( To configure Group Level, Need to configure Group Level JVM configuration in Management Console )

**4. Node Level** ( To Configure Node Level,Need to configure Node Level JVM configuration in Management Console )

*The above is the hierarchy too. But Its precedence is completely reverse. That means, Node Level takes highest precedence than Group Level. As well as Group Level takes highest precedence than Host Level.*

> 1 ) What is the Default Node level JVM Configuration, If i haven't specified any Configuration at Node Level?

It will check Group Level / Host Level Configurations. If we specified Group Level Configurations , It will took it. In case, If we haven't configured Group Level, It will take Host level configurations (We are having default Host Level Configurations).

> 2 ) Group Level Configuration will affect Node Level Configuration ?

Nope, It will not affect. Instead, Node Level JVM Configuration will override Group Level Configurations.